# Pytest html report is not showing in html format in jenkins

Tags: html, api, jenkins, pytest

If i do the execution in local we can see the report in html format. Even if we do the execution through jenkins it is generation in html format only.

But for viewing it is not shwoing as expected.

Please find the below diffferences for both.

if i open jenkins report by downloading it is opening normally like how we are seeing manual execution report. If i try to open this from jenkins then we are getting below issue.

Jenkins report

[image: Jenkins execution report]
Locan execution report

[image: Local execution report]

Answer (score 1):

have similar problem
This happens because of 'Content-Security-Policy' of Jenkins is blocking the inline CSS, JS Ajax resources to load

The solution to this is start Jenkins server with below command

```
java -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="" -jar jenkins.war
```

[image]

more you can [read here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/security/configuring-content-security-policy/#ConfiguringContentSecurityPolicy-HTMLPublisherPlugin)