# Pytest html report is not showing in html format

Tags: python, selenium, pytest-html

I have python selenium automation and I am executing them using pytest. The pytest html report is getting generated but the format does not have CSS. Earlier it was working fine and I was getting a proper report with CSS, but now I am getting just a raw HTML report. My issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64222757/pytest-html-report-is-not-showing-in-html-format-in-jenkins)

I am not sure what exactly is the issue. Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If viewing `pytest-html` reports in Jenkins, you may need to configure the Jenkins settings (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46197356) for the HTML to render correctly. This is due to [Jenkins CSP changes](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/configuring-content-security-policy/). That setting can be changed from `Manage Jenkins` > `Script Console` by running:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")
```